# Python csv tags

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with different headers.

```
name,city
john doe,chicago
```

Have headers as

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(PATH_FILE),skipinitialspace=True)
headers = reader.fieldnames
```

How will you  run a regex that whenever a tag [name] was to be proceesed it will show "john doe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) with a function passed as `repl`, or you could just use [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) with a mapping:

```
print 'My name is %(name)s' % rowdict
```